# Erratic behavior of a print(2d list) in nested for loops python (swapping list items inside the loops)

Tags: python

I'm trying to swap 1 with 2 and 2 with 1 inside a 2d list in two nested for loops. I also display the list before and after in both loops  -

```
def train(cls, isSomethingTrue): #isSomethingTrue is always false
    print('before {0}'.format(cls.xtrain))
    for i in range(len(cls.xtrain)):
        print('before {0}'.format(cls.xtrain[i]))
        cls.ytrain.append([1, 0])
        if(not isSomethingTrue):
            for j in range(len(cls.xtrain[i])):
                if cls.xtrain[i][j] == 1:
                    cls.xtrain[i][j] = 2
                    continue
                elif cls.xtrain[i][j] == 2:
                    cls.xtrain[i][j] = 1
                    continue
        print('after {0}'.format(cls.xtrain[i]))
    print('after {0}'.format(cls.xtrain))
```

The problem is that the outer loop shows only even indices to be swapped (the inner loop works as expected). How's that possible?

Here is the screenshot as well -

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue. I tried filling in the blanks in your program to get it to run and my final "after" doesn't match yours at all.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code. Could it be that `cls.xtrain` contains the same list multiple times? Like `li= [1,2]; xtrain= [li, li]`.

Comment: @Kevin Strangely, I just tried to initialize `cls.xtrain` inside the method and then it worked! But when `cls.xtrain` is updated elsewhere (in another method of another class), it still doesn't. I'll try to create another project that tries to capture the method calls because this one is too complicated to post here.

Comment: @Rawing Yes, 'cls.train` is usually updated as 'cls.xtrain.append( instanceOfSomeOtherClass.SomeList)`. That's a good hint, I'll try to deepcopy the `SomeList`.

Comment: @Rawing Yes, that was it! deepycopying the list before appending seems to have fixed it. Still not sure why the inner loop was working and why the list items were not all same, but it works for now. Feel free to add your comment as an answer if you like.